# We have already running windows process. How to determine what parameters it has been ran with?

Tags: windows, shell, windows-services, process, windows-xp

For example I have a running process seen in windows task manager (.exe). I'd like to see the parameters that's been passed to the process when it was started. I do not start this proces, nor I have any control or an easy way of debugging the spot it's getting started. Any suggestions ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See if this works for you:
http://windowsxp.mvps.org/listproc.htm

> Type the command given below exactly:
>
> WMIC /OUTPUT:C:\ProcessList.txt
>   PROCESS get
>   Caption,Commandline,Processid
>
> or
>
> WMIC /OUTPUT:C:\ProcessList.txt path
>   win32_process get
>   Caption,Processid,Commandline
>
> Now, open the file C:\ProcessList.txt.
>   You can see the details of all the
>   processes in that file.